# SQL joining on names

Tags: sql, join, substring, names

I am querying two tables and joining them together on people's names.  I am trying to produce all employees who have not filled out a form within the past month.  The problem I am encountering is I am receiving an overlap of names when people list their short name (Joe rather than Joseph, or Mike rather than Michael).  How can I still produce the list of people without overlap, even when they use their short names?

This is the query I have as of now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ge.employeeNo,
(ge.firstName + ' ' + ge.lastName) AS empName,
ge.email
FROM dbo.hist_Employees ge
INNER JOIN dbo.ctrl_Sites cs ON ge.locationID = cs.ID
WHERE (ge.firstName + ' ' + ge.lastName) NOT IN
    (SELECT sc.recordedBy
    FROM GRSTOPS.dbo.hist_StopCard sc
    INNER JOIN dbo.ctrl_Area a ON sc.area = a.ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.ctrl_Site s ON a.site = s.ID
    WHERE sc.recorded BETWEEN '10/01/2013' AND '10/30/2013'
        AND s.code = 'gre')
AND cs.Abbreviation = 'gre'
AND ge.employmentStatus = 1
AND ge.primaryDept <> 3
```

Comment: I think the only safe way to use unique ids. It can happen that 2 people's name are 100% the same.

Comment: I agree that a Unique ID would be the best route, but as the StopCard table is a user filled out form, and the employees do not know their employee ID's it is not an available option.

Comment: A primary key is used to uniquely identify each row in a table. It can either be part of the actual record itself , or it can be an artificial field (one that has no meaning other than being an identifier of the record). How to set primary keys is an important factor in database design, as the choices of primary key can have significant impact on the performance, usability, and the extensibility of the entire database.

Comment: I think the short answer is, "you can't".

Answer (score 0):

It would be better not to join on peoples names as they are not unique.
You should join using a primary key like ID/employeeNo etc.